# SQLException: Select statement throw exception The index 1 is out of range

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlexception

I tried connect to MS SQL Server but when i debut it and i get SQLException.

> PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from dbo.theLogin tl;]; The
>   index 1 is out of range

```
public ArrayList<Login> select(String username, String password) {
    JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    return  (ArrayList<Login>) select.query(
                    "select tl.username, tl.password from dbo.theLogin tl;",
                    new Object[] {username, password},
                    new LoginRowMapper());
}
```

I cannot figure out what wrong it. Please help. Thanks in advancen

Comment: Tag the language that your code sample was taken from.   The problem isn't in the SQL.

Comment: I"m using Java.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to your `query()` call should be a list of values to use to bind to any variables in the SQL statement - but your SQL does not have any variables to bind to, so you get that "index 1 is out of range" when it tries to set the first parameter to the value of `username`.  Your SQL looks like it will return a list of all username and password pairs from your table - which may not be what you were after...